# Why is the point $x=0$ not a periodic point of $f(x)=1/x$ of period $2$?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

In a question I am trying to solve, I am asked to prove that $x=0,1$ and $-1$ are not points of period $2$ for $f(x)=1/x$. I get why $x=1,-1$ aren't points of period $2$ but why is $x=0$ not a periodic point because

$$
f(f(x))=x
$$

and so $f^{[2]}(0)=0$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ except $0$.

Comment: Your equation is true for all points *in the domain of* $f$, but $0$ is not such a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $f(0)$? The way you have defined $f(x)$, $0$ is not in the domain, so it doesn't make sense to talk about periodicity of the point.